# How to get or create new map entry

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a simple utility function to get a value from a Map and, if it's not found to create a new value class and put that in the map.

It seems though very difficult to get the classes of the map's key and value at runtime and the best I can come up with is something horrible along the following lines.

Is there a better way?

```
private Object getOrCreate( Map<Object, Object> map, Object key, Class<?> mapValueClass ) {
    Object value = map.get( key );      

    if (value == null) {                     
        Constructor<?> con = mapValueClass.getConstructor( key.getClass() );
        value = con.newInstance( key );  
        map.put( key, value );               
    }

    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should ckeck out [`Map::getOrDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) and [`Map::computeIfAbsent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) (added in Java 8); those do pretty much exactly what your function is supposed to do. The difference between the two is that `getOrDefault` will accept an existing instance (created before the method is invoked) and return it if needed, but will not add it to the map, while `computeIfAbsend` accepts a function for lazily creating a new value, and will also add that value to the map.

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

List<Integer> list1 = map.getOrDefault("foo", Collections.emptyList());
System.out.println(list1); // empty list
System.out.println(map);   // map is still empty

List<Integer> list2 = map.computeIfAbsent("bar", s -> new ArrayList<Integer>());
System.out.println(list2); // empty list
System.out.println(map);   // entry added to map
```

Assuming that you always want to create a new instance of the Value class with the key as parameter, and assuming that that class actually has such a constructor) you could e.g. use this:

```
YourClass obj = map.computeIfAbsent(key, YourClass::new);
```